# Handle result of ajax request in Ruby on Rails received in json format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json, haml

I'm trying to authenticate through AJAX and can not figure out how to show a message when ajax request is finished. When email and password are invalid, I need to show an error message.

The code of a haml page

```
=form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :remote => true, :format => :json) do |f| 
    = label :user, :email, "Email"
    = text_field :user, :email
    = label :user, :password
    = password_field :user, :password
    %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Sign in"}
```

and the result
[image]

Your ideas?

Comment: We will need your UsersController/SessionsController code to answer your question.

Comment: Yes what does the controller look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using JSON format (only data, not actions), you need some kind of client-side processing.

Try to process response in `ajax:success` handler. With jQuery it can be something like:

```
$('#the_form_id').on('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {
  if(data) {
    if(data.status) { // Login successful
      alert("Login successful");
    }
    else {
      alert(data.errors);
      // To show errors inside a DOM element
      $("#error-wrapper").html(data.errors);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: In an ajax request you have to take care of displaying your message yourself. If you have a specific container / dom element reserved for displaying the flash message, you can modifiy dimuchs answer to display the message there.